# Align text vertically inside a <a href="" class="btn">Text</a> in Bootstrap 3/4

Tags: button, hyperlink, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-4

This is my website html:

```
<div class="row">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Text
      </a>
</div>
```

Do I have to change my html? or add a class in my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little changes in your html structure are required

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Text
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```